On the Display of Quotation Marks When Using the EB Garamond Font
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\fontspec{EB Garamond}

``This is a quote.''

{\scshape{``This is a quote.''}}
\end{document}

which produces

QUESTION: When using the EB Garamond font, it appears that the closing double quotes do not represent a vertical reflection of the associated opening double quotes. Can this be corrected so that the closing quotes on the right appear to be a mirror image of those on the left? If so, how; and would that be bad typography? I compile the code with lualatex.
Thank you.

you need \fontspec[Ligatures=TeX]{EB Garamond}, or use \setmainfont{EB Garamond}.

@UlrikeFischer Many thanks; your recommendation appears to give matching opening and closing quotes (curly though).  I was hoping to keep the style of the opening quotes as they appear above. But for uniformity, your suggestion does indeed do the trick. Thank you.

you don't get quotes with your document, on the right you get two grave accents (U+60) and on the left two apostrophs (U+27).

@UlrikeFischer Oh, I thought that is how one is supposed to indicate opening and closing quotes in the code. Did I do something wrong in the code for this purpose?

in the code it is fine if you enable ligatures so that they get converted into quotes in the output. (Personally I have shortcuts and either use real (german) quotes „“ or \enquote{} in my input).

@UlrikeFischer Ah; thank you for these helpful suggestions.

Don't use \fontspec in order to do a font choice; see \setmainfont vs \fontspec. The command is supposed to be helpful for presenting showcases of fonts.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}

``This is a quote.''

\textsc{``This is a quote.''}

\end{document}


If you actually want to do a showcase, tell LaTeX that you want the standard ligatures to be enabled.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\begin{document}

\fontspec{EB Garamond}

``This is a quote.''

\textsc{``This is a quote.''}

\end{document}

Note that \scshape doesn't take an argument. So {\scshape Text} is almost equivalent to \textsc{Text}, but you should prefer the latter.
